# pass datetime parameter in URL string

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

This is how I want to call my REST API filtering on date range:

curl "127.0.0.1:5000/report?start=10%2F06%2F2015%2007%3A00%3A00&end=10%2F07%2F2015%2006%3A59%3A59"

where %2F is forward slash
and %3A is colon

On parsing this URL here: http://www.freeformatter.com/url-parser-query-string-splitter.html
I'm getting correct fields

This is the script I have so far:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_restful import reqparse
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
e = create_engine("x")

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('start', type = str)
parser.add_argument('end', type = str)

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Report(Resource):

    def get(self):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        conn = e.connect()

        stat = """
        select id from report where dates between ? and ?
        """

        query = conn.execute(stat, [[args[0], args[1]])

        for i in query.cursor.fetchall():
            return {'id': i[0]}

api.add_resource(Report, '/report')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> C:\Users\x>
>   curl "127.0.0.1:5000/report?start=10%2F06%2F2015%2007%3A00%3A00&end=10%2F07%2F2015%2006%3A59%3A59"
>    {"message": "an integer is required (got type str)"}

Comment: Is report.dates an integer or datetime field?

Comment: its a datetime field in the sql database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem is that you're accessing a dict (args) by index. Reqparse creates a dictionary, not an array. You should access your parameters using `args['start']` and `args['end']`.

Your line would look like this:

```
query = conn.execute(stat, [args['start'], args['end']])
```

Additionally, your return is not correct. Change `return {'id': i[0]}` to `return {'id': i}` since `i` in this case is not an array.

One last thing, I highly suggest using http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/ instead of using raw SQL queries.

Comment: Strange. Try using named arguments in your SQL query, rather than positional. It would look like `select id from report where dates between :start and :end`, and `query = conn.execute(stat, start=args['start'], end=args['end'])`

Comment: hey brian! thanks for your help. fixed it by changing the last line to this:
            return {'id': str(i[0])}